# Control execution flow of TThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

How can I Pause/Continue `TThread` I am looking for a safe alternative to the deprecated `TThread.Suspend` aswell as `TThread.Resume`.

Comment: In the `Execute` method loop wait for an event.

Comment: @TLama WaitForMultipleObjects maybe?

Comment: Yes, WaitForSingleObject or WaitForMultipleObjects is what you are looking for. Some more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4401519/800214)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up with. Safe alternative to Suspend/Resume.

```
     type
      TMyThread = class(TThread)
      private
        FHandles: array[0..1] of THandle;
      protected
        procedure Execute; override;
      public
        constructor Create;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Pause;
        procedure UnPause;
        procedure Stop;
      end;

      constructor TMyThread.Create;
      begin
        inherited Create(False);
        FHandles[0] := CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
        FHandles[1] := CreateEvent(nil, True, True, nil);
        FreeOnTerminate := True;
      end;

      destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
      begin
        CloseHandle(FHandles[1]);
        CloseHandle(FHandles[0]);
        inherited Destroy;
      end;

      procedure TMyThread.Execute;
      begin
        while not Terminated do
        begin
          case WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @FHandles[0], False, INFINITE) of
            WAIT_FAILED:
              RaiseLastOsError;
            WAIT_OBJECT_0:
              Terminate;
            WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
              begin

              end;
          end;
        end;

      end;

      procedure TMyThread.Pause;
      begin
        ResetEvent(FHandles[1]);
      end;

      procedure TMyThread.UnPause;
      begin
        SetEvent(FHandles[1]);
      end;

      procedure TMyThread.Stop;
      begin
        SetEvent(FHandles[0]);
      end;
```

Comment: I'm having something similar in my threads (because I'm targeting only Windows platform and do not like the `TEvent` class). One thing I would improve in this code. In the `Stop` method I would write just `Terminate` and the exit event I would signal in the `TerminatedSet` method. That allows to *gracefully* exit your thread when the application terminates (without the need to calling `Stop`). In the `Execute` method you can then just `Exit` when this event is signalled. It is also good to identify the events somehow. Maybe [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/8JdA4prE).

Comment: @TLama This is even better! Thanks! :)

Comment: @TLama: thanks for the `TerminatedSet()` hint, I never knew about that one. Looks like it was introduced in/near XE2.