# "Pausing" A Thread With A Property

Tags: multithreading, delphi, critical-section, pause, tthread

I have a TThread object and want to be able to start/stop the thread via a button on the main form of the program. I've been looking into ways to do this and so far I have the following ideas:

1. Terminate and Free the thread when the user clicks stop and create a new one when they click start.
2. Use sleep to delay the thread (I don't want to do this)
3. Have a property that is a boolean to determine if the thread is paused or not. The code in the Execute will only happen if this boolean is false.

I'm leaning towards #3. Would setting a boolean property on the TThread object from the main form be threadsafe?

Which of these options, or any better alternative, should I go with? This is my first time using threads so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Recent versions of Delphi don't allow pausing/resuming threads, because the entire design (and concept) was flawed. You should avoid attempting to do so and switch to using signalled events (e.g., TEvent) instead. See the various event types in SyncObjs.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401171/self-suspending-a-thread-in-delphi-when-its-not-needed-and-safely-resuming

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1.Terminate and Free the thread when the user clicks stop and create a new one when they click start.

This is certainly an option, if the overhead is minimal.

> 3.Have a property that is a boolean to determine if the thread is paused or not. The code in the Execute will only happen if this boolean is false.

You could do that, but you would have to check that boolean regularly and if set then enter a wait loop until either it is cleared or the thread is signaled to terminate.

> Would setting a boolean property on the TThread object from the main form be threadsafe?

It is as thread-safe as calling `TThread.Terminate()`, which simply sets the boolean `TThread.Terminated` property.

> Which of these options, or any better alternative, should I go with?

I use option #4 - using signaled events instead of booleans.  For example:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FRunEvent, FTermEvent: TEvent;
    FWaitEvents: THandleObjectArray;
    procedure CheckPause;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Pause;
    procedure Unpause;
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);

  FRunEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, True, '');
  FTermEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');

  SetLength(FWaitEvents, 2);
  FWaitEvents[0] := FRunEvent;
  FWaitEvents[1] := FTermEvent;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  FRunEvent.Free;
  FTermEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    // do some work...
    CheckPause;
    // do some more work...
    CheckPause;
    // do some more work...
    CheckPause;
    //...
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FTermEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TMyThread.CheckPause;
var
  SignaledEvent: THandleObject;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    case TEvent.WaitForMultiple(FWaitEvents, INFINITE, False, SignaledEvent) of
      wrSignaled: begin
        if SignaledEvent = FRunEvent then Exit;
        Break;
      end;
      wrIOCompletion: begin
        // retry
      end;
      wrError: begin
        RaiseLastOSError;
    end;
  end;
  SysUtils.Abort;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Pause;
begin
  FRunEvent.ResetEvent;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Unpause;
begin
  FRunEvent.SetEvent;
end;
```

Comment: Remy, What is `SysUtils.Abort;` in the `CheckPause` method used for.

Comment: It raises an `EAbort` exception to immediately terminate the thread (since `Execute()` does not catch it) the next time `CheckPause()` is called after `Terminate()` has been called.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the wiki for Delphi on starting and stopping threads here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Starting_and_Stopping_Threads

This is applicable as far back as Delphi 7.  It may be applicable farther back, but I cannot confirm earlier versions.

Comment: This is a comment to the question, not an answer. Answers contain the relevant information here, in the post itself, with links used only to provide additional reference. Answers should stand on their own, so that they contain value if the off-site location is unavailable for some reason (moved, off-line, or whatever). Link only answers do not do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have not answered the question. The question requests a recommendation, but you have neglected to provide one. Please [edit] your answer so that it addresses what the question asks for.